# Installing Ubuntu on blank hard drive for 2013 Macbook Pro

Tags: boot, hard-drive, macbook-pro

I got a Macbook Pro from a friend of mine, no hard drive.

So I thought, I'll just toss an old hard drive into it and install Ubuntu from a flash drive.

Unfortunately, when I try to boot with an Ubuntu USB drive I get the following message: "No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key"

Ok, no problem, I'll just toss the hard drive into my current desktop, boot from the Ubuntu USB and install it that way.

And that went great! The USB drive booted perfectly, installing Ubuntu onto the hard drive went well. I was able to boot up my desktop using my new Ubuntu hard drive.

But when I put the Ubuntu hard drive into the Macbook, it gives me the same "No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key" message.

Even more confusing, is that I have an old hard drive with ElementaryOS on it, and THAT one booted perfectly in the Macbook!

Whaaat the heck is going on???

Comment: Did you press and hold Option while booting the Mac?

Comment: You should end up with the option to boot Windows/EFI boot from USB.

Comment: I did. I got a message along the lines of: No operating system installed.

Comment: Does this USB work on other machines?

Comment: Check this out: http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot-short-version/